# Android Notification Update Periodically Silently Not Working (Handler issue?)

Tags: java, android, loops, notifications, handler

Working on my first android app so I am a complete noob so I'm probably making a silly mistake but I cannot get the notification text to update periodically. It works if I reclick the toggle button but I want the notification to update automatically if the week number has changed and to refresh the notification silently. Included a snippet of my code, thanks for the help in advance.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


    public void createNotification() {

       final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
       now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

       int weekId = 1;
       final NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
               .setContentTitle("Week")
               .setContentText(""+now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR))
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
       final NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       NM.notify(weekId, nBuilder.build());

    }

    // Init
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createNotification();
            Log.i(TAG, "updated");
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    createNotification();
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    NM.cancelAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000)` is never being called because `run()` is never being called. Try adding a `handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000)` to your 'onCreate()' to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Its working now. Its interesting how according to Logcat the handler in the "onCreate" runs once then it looks like it references back the original handler and keeps looping that one while "killing" the "onCreate" one.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
if (isChecked) {
    // The toggle is enabled
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
} else {
    // The toggle is disabled
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.cancel(1);
}
```